# Find the Fourier series for the function $f(x) = x^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

How do I start solving this question, what are the steps?

a) Find the Fourier series for the function $f(x) = x^4$ on the interval $[−π, π]$.

b) Hence prove that $$1-\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}-\frac{1}{4^4}+.....=\frac{7\pi ^4}{720}$$

using

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^2}\right)=\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

We need to calculate the coefficients $a_n$ of the cosine series.  To do so, we will determine the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^4\cos (ax)\,dx\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\frac{d^4}{da^4}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{iax}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\text{Re}\left(\frac{d^4}{da^4}\frac{2\sin (\pi a)}{a}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{d^4}{da^4}\frac{2\sin (\pi a)}{a}\\\\
&=\frac{2\sin(\pi a)}{a^5}\left((\pi a)^4-12(\pi a)^2+24\right)+\frac{2\cos(\pi a)}{a^5}\left(4(\pi a)^3-24(\pi a)\right)
\end{align}$$

Setting $a=n$ gives

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^4\cos (nx)\,dx&=(-1)^n\frac{8(\pi n)^3-48(\pi n)}{n^5}\\\\
&=(-1)^n \frac{8\pi^3}{n^2}-(-1)^n \frac{48\pi}{n^4}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$x^4=\pi^4/5+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((-1)^n \frac{8\pi^2}{n^2}-(-1)^n \frac{48}{n^4}\right)\,\cos(nx) \tag 1$$

Setting $x=0$ in $(1)$ yields

$$0=\pi^4/5+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((-1)^n \frac{8\pi^2}{n^2}-(-1)^n \frac{48}{n^4}\right) \tag 2$$

whereupon solving $(2)$ for the series of interest reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^4}&=\frac1{48}\left(-\pi^4/5+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{8\pi^2}{n^2}\right)  \\\\
&=\frac1{48}\left(-\pi^4/5+8\pi^4/12\right) \\\\
&=\frac{7\pi^4}{20}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I don't understand what you did in the second step? can you please explain it in words, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure.  Using Euler's Formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$, we see the $\cos  a x=\text{Re}\left(e^{iax}\right)$.  In addition, $$\frac{d^4 e^{iax}}{da^4}=x^4 e^{iax}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^4$ is even, so you only need cosines. Fourier coefficient is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^4\cos(nx)dx$, which can be computed by integration by parts. Once you are done, just compute $f(1)$.